# Android scrollview and keyboard issue

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a view that has a ScrollView as root layout that has a background set. 
When the keyboard pops up, I want the ScrollView to shrink so that it stays above the keyboard, but I want the background image to stay the same. It currently shrinks with the view.
I know I need to use `adjustResize` to keep the ScrollView on top and I can switch to `adjustNothing` to get the ScrollView behind the keyboard, but that way I would have EditTexts behind the keyboard.

Any idea/help is welcome!

Basically, I want the `adjustResize` behavior with the background acting as in `adjustNothing`.

Here are some screenshots:
[image: adjustNothing]
[image: adjustResize]
[image: Normal aspect]

Comment: a screenshot will be appreciated :)

Comment: Please provide a screenhot

Comment: paste manifest code here

Comment: I cannot do that, but it's pretty obvious that I am asking for a set of settings that would work, I did search a lot about it and couldn't find the answer, therefore what I have now is not important.